# Ressource access in groovy project via jenkins

Tags: java, pdf, grails, jenkins, groovy

I am developping a Webapp using Groovy Grails Tools Suit.
in this app, i have to create a pdf starting from an existing one.
In local, i am doing this using itext and loading the existing pdf like this:

```
PdfReader reader= new PdfReader("Doc.pdf");
```

It work fine but only in local , now i have to do this when the app is executing from Jenkins .
With this code, i got this error:

> java.io.IOException: DocDeBase30.pdf not found as file or resource.

I think its a problem of security access but i don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: if you don't have security access then it's simply a matter of doing a chmod a+wr on the pdf. More likely I think it's that Jenkins is executing from his home folder (default /var/jenkins/something) and doesn't have the file in view. Provide an absolute path to the document and it should be able to find it.